# Streaming data with RESTKit

Tags: ios, restkit

I would like to know if there is any way (or fork project of RESTKit) that allows to do streaming of the HTTP response body instead of loading everything in memory like RESTKit is currently doing.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking over the code, it doesn't look like that RestKit suports streaming of the response body.

It looks like you might need another solution. I hear AFNetworking is really good for doing the networking part of it (I haven't used it yet myself). And I've used "YAJL" to do a streaming JSON parser. Apparently AFNetworking can hook into YAJL... not sure how this would work, but you might look into this.